# Read values from Google Sheet via Google Apps Script are different then original sheet value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I observed something weird.
I am getting values from a sheet with a script.
Some value are dates like here.
[image]

When I read the value with:

```
function test2() {
    var startCell = ss.getRange("B24");
    var i = 0;
    var val;
    ...

    //Reading columns data
    while (startCell.offset(0,i).getValue() != '') {
      ...
      val = startCell.offset(-21,i).getValue();
      i++;
    }
    ...
};
```

When I look now at the value in the script debugger the value changed.

[image]

In that case there are additional **50min 39sec**.
Am I doing something wrong?

Warm regards

Answer (score 1):

Datetime conversion between systems is quite complex in the general case. For example, if the spreadsheet's timezone differs from the script project's timezone, there will be differences in what the datetime looks like in the spreadsheet and what it looks like when read and output by a script.

The weird looking 0:50:39 offset you mention could be because the region that currently observes the CEST timezone was back *in the year 1900* using some local time that was offset by say 1 hour, 50 minutes and 39 seconds from GMT, instead of an offset that would be exactly one, two, three or so hours from GMT.

A well-documented example of these issues is the American [railway time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_time#United_States) which had as many as 50 different local times across United States. The present US time zones were taken into use only in 1918.

Usually the easiest way to manage these differences is to use `Utilities.formatDate()` and the *spreadsheet's* timezone when producing human-readable outputs, like this:

```
function testDateOutput() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const date = ss.getRange('Sheet1!B24').getValue();
  const timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  console.log(Utilities.formatDate(date, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
}
```

Note that the above method does not give perfect results for any and all moments and timezones because of the complexities mentioned above, especially with dates that are more than 50 years in the past.

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.